# Yii фрейм и render?

Tags: yii

Может я чего то не понимаю. Смысл проблемы в чем.
Пусть есть дерево страниц, рисуется в layout в column2 предположим. При клике на ссылку дерева должна отображаться та или иная страница. Страницы не обязательно сделаны в фреймворке. Сейчас большинство из них - просто странички на пхп. Соответственно при нажатии на ссылку я в получается $content отображаю frameset.php, лежащий в site\pages
Внутри этого файла

```
$page = Page::model()->findByPk($page)->link;    
    echo '
    <iframe id="ifr" src="' . $page . '" align="center">    
    </iframe>';
```

то есть отдаю я ид страницы. а фрейм её подгружает.
но при клике перезагружается вся страница, а мне нужно чтобы только фрейм перезагружался, а дерево не менялось.
как поступают в данном случае?
и соответсвенно вопрос в догонку - а как быть со страницами на yii ?
не могу понять как по ссылке отображать только $content.
смотрю в сторону render но ему же вроде как представление нужно а не просто страничка?

--

появилась шальная мысль - делаем пункты карты ajaxlink.

соответственно в контроллер передаем id\url.

в ajaxoption выставляем update => content. при этом в контролере должен отработать скрипт window.location.href(url).

ну это в порядке бреда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail
Выводит чисто $content без layout, если я правильно понял

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: да не ответ это ни разу. если у меня страничка <?php echo 'hello world'; ?> (на другом сервере причем) то никакого layout у нее нет